# Webpack build very slow because of external libraries

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I try use webpack to my app, but it build my app for 60-100sec each time.
How can i disable rebuild files from `node_modules/*` and  `bower_components/*` or build them for separate chunk (per module or shared).

here is part of config:

```
 {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel-loader']
 },
```

and

```
resolve: {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components']
},
```

How can i improve performance, by disabling rebuilding of libraries at each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to bundle vendor scripts separately.
See this [**answer** (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38733864/3861851)

Comment: The links are broken now.

Comment: Yep, semms like author remove those docs. Try search here
http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/

Comment: Try to search those links on your behalf and please edit the answer here to prevent downvoting (trolls love doing that ;-) )