# How to access modules bundled from webpack outside bundles/chunks

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, dependencies, webpack

Let me first say that I have tried searching for an answer to this and haven't found anything that works or even hints to it being possible.

I recently moved from RequireJS configuration to rolling up with Webpack. In some places in our Groovy app we have have a script tag in a GSP that will access modules through RequireJS like so:

```
<html>
<body>
...

  <script>
      require([
          'jquery',
          'customModule'
      ], function($, customModule){
          // do something with jquery
          // ...
          // do something with customModule
      });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would need to be able to do the equivalent with Webpack for a few reasons, the most important is our ability to inject Javascript from our admin side to hotfix any production bugs without pushing a maintenance release.

Expecting I should be able to do something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
...

  <script>
      webpack_require([
          'jquery',
          'customModule'
      ], function($, customModule){
          // do something with jquery
          // ...
          // do something with customModule
      });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you know how to access Webpack bundles from the outside please share! Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34361312/3318377)!

Comment: That's awesome, thanks @halloei !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag)