# Webpack - react works even when it's not in 'vendors'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm working with Webpack+React and I'm using the CommonsChunkPlugin. The thing is that react works even when I don't put it in the 'vendors' entry (same for other packages). Does that make sense?

My config looks like this:

```
config.entry.vendors = ['mobx', 'jquery', 'highcharts', 'react-highcharts', 'moment', 'numeral', 'jquery-ui', 'jquery.cookie', 'lodash', 'jquery.waitforimages', 'raven-js'];

config.module.loaders = config.module.loaders.concat([
  {
    test  : /\.less$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: "style-loader",
      loader  : "css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!less-loader?sourceMap"
    })
  }
]);

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[chunkhash].min.css'),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    minimize  : true,
    mangle    : false, // { except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require'] },
    compressor: {
      warnings : false,
      screw_ie8: true
    },
    sourceMap : true
  }),
  new StatsPlugin('webpack.stats.json', {
    source : false,
    modules: false
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendors', filename: 'vendors-[chunkhash].min.js'}),
  new WebpackMd5Hash(),
  new ManifestPlugin(),
  new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin({
    name: 'webpackManifest'
  })
]);
```

The output value of webpack is:

```
  output: {
    filename         : '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath       : '/',
    path             : paths.dist,
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map",
  },
```

Comment: It mostly depends on how you're using CommonsChunkPlugin, could you please post webpack config here?

Comment: @havenchyk added the config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bundle vendor scripts separately and require them as needed with Webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329337/how-to-bundle-vendor-scripts-separately-and-require-them-as-needed-with-webpack)

Comment: Not sure it's a duplication ... I'm just wondering how come react is working if it's not included in the 'vendors' list?

Comment: @refaelos could you please also put `output` from webpack config?

Comment: @havenchyk added output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommonsChunkPlugin` is smart enough, you didn't specify `chunks` property for `CommonsChunkPlugin`, that means that plugin will try to go through all your entries and move common parts to **vendors** chunk and then into **vendors-[chunkhash].min.js** file.

e.g. you have 2 entry points: `index.js`, `signin.js` and in both you have next code:

```
const React = require('react')
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
```

So with configuration like

```
entry: {
    app: './index.js',
    signin: './signin.js',
    vendor: ['react']
},
*****
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
         name: 'vendor',
         filename: 'vendor-[chunkhash].js'
    })
]
```

you will still have `react-dom` in vendor chunk.

On another hand if you have third entry point without requiring `react-dom`, only `react` will be moved to vendor chunk.

But even in this case you will still have `react-dom` included into first two entry chunks.

> The thing is that react works event when I don't put it in the 'vendors' entry (same for other packages).

So react will work in any case, the only difference will be, will `react` chunk be moved to `vendors` or not, if not, it still will be included in your entry point file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! So react is included in the entry point file. If I add it to 'vendors' it'll be included in vendors file and removed from entry point file?