# How to speed up an Azure web application deployment with lots of files?

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, octopus-deploy

At my work we have a .NET web application that is hosted in Azure. We use TeamCity to build our application and Octopus to deploy the application to Azure. We've been noticing that our deployments have started to increase in duration so I've been looking at the Octopus logs and it appears that the duration is mainly due to the multitude of front-end files we are using. We have recently implemented React so we have the `node_modules` folder plus all the other `.css` and `.js` plugin files that our front-end uses.

Are there any strategies to deal with said files and reduce the burden on deployments? Open to crazy ideas like zipping or using Docker containers - anything to make the deployments scale better as our application gets larger.

Comment: when did zipping become crazy?

Comment: What does your deployment process actually look like? I would have assumed that this is a pretty vanilla "Deploy NuGet" step, followed by web site configuration to point at the extracted folder. It's early... I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with the hype and use **[webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)**?
As opposed to other hypes.. this is practical and actually useful.

[image: webpack-mechanics]

Image source: http://www.pro-react.com/materials/appendixA/

Comment: We use webpack to bundle our own React files. Are you suggesting we use webpack for **all** javascript and css files, ours and third party?

Comment: Yes, you could also bundle 3rd party stuff separately - here's a broader thread on that -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329337/how-to-bundle-vendor-scripts-separately-and-require-them-as-needed-with-webpack

Comment: Alternatively you could .zip everything up and call Kudu's ZIP API if you're hosted on App Service -- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip