# webpack2 code splitting and CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack-2

I ran into a problem using code splitting and the CommonsChunkPlugin. I'm used to `require.js` where the files are cached automatically. I'm also using the `libraryTarget: 'amd'` for my webpack configuration.

Considering these two simple files, this is the output I get:

```
// fileA.js
import $ from 'jquery'

// fileB.js
import $ from 'jquery'

   Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
fileB.js  271 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  fileB
fileA.js  271 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  fileA
```

So both files, `fileA` and `fileB` have `jquery` included. Also, I'm able to use these files like this in my `html` file.

```
require(['./dist/fileA.js', './dist/fileB.js'], function () {
})
```

As per the docs I can use the `CommonsChunkPlugin` to basically extract jquery into its own file, so my config looks like this:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common'
}),
```

resulting in this output:

```
    Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
 fileB.js  635 bytes       0  [emitted]         fileB
 fileA.js  617 bytes       1  [emitted]         fileA
common.js     274 kB       2  [emitted]  [big]  common
```

**BUT** now I'm unable to use the above `require` block, because the `common.js` also includes the webpack runtime. All I now get is an `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined` error.

So what I would need is:

1. fileA.js (only contains "fileA" code, requiring jquery)
2. fileB.js (only contains "fileB" code, requiring jquery)
3. jquery.js (all of the jquery stuff)
4. common.js (only contains the runtime for webpack)

I already tried something like this for `fileA` and `fileB`, but it's basically the same output:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

})
```

A (Vendor) library should only be loaded, if a script (like `fileA`) is loaded and has it as a dependency (as it is with requirejs).

Can this be accomplished? I skimmed through the webpack2 docs numerous times, but couldn't find anything that could help me...

edit: Ok, with the help of some github issues, I managed to get the correct asset generation with the following configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    jquery: ['jquery'],
    vue: ['vue'],
    fileA: ['./src/fileA.js'],
    fileB: ['./src/fileB.js'],
    fileC: ['./src/fileC.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist',
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'amd'
  }
}

module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['vue', 'jquery']
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    chunks: ['vue', 'jquery'],
    minChunks: Infinity
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
])
```

I changed the source files to:

```
// fileA.js
import $ from 'jquery'
import Vue from 'vue'
// fileB.js
import $ from 'jquery'
// fileC.js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

And this is the output:

```
   vue.js     193 kB       0  [emitted]         vue
 fileC.js  447 bytes       1  [emitted]         fileC
 fileB.js  579 bytes       2  [emitted]         fileB
 fileA.js  666 bytes       3  [emitted]         fileA
jquery.js     269 kB       4  [emitted]  [big]  jquery
common.js    5.78 kB       5  [emitted]         common
```

However, using it in an `.html` file like so results in the following error:

```
<body>
  <script src="./dist/common.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.js"></script>
  <script>
    require(['./dist/fileA.js', './dist/fileB.js', './dist/fileC.js'], function (a, b, c) {
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

The following error occurs both for `fileA` and for `fileC`...

```
common.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (common.js:55)
    at Object.7 (fileA.js:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (common.js:55)
    at Object.6 (fileA.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (common.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (common.js:26)
    at fileA.js:1
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696)
    at Module.check (require.js:883)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1176)
```

**edit:**

I've create a [repo on github](https://github.com/johannes-z/webpack-test) showing the problem I ran into. As per the answer of Rafael De Leon, I'm now using `System.import('<module>')` to asynchronously import other files. `main.ts` imports `fileA.ts` via this syntax, resulting in an error when `output.js` (the compiled `main.ts` file) is required. The error seems to happen when `fileA` is being loaded from withing `output.js`... I've also created a [github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5264), because I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> A (Vendor) library should only be loaded, if a script (like fileA) is loaded and has it as a dependency (as it is with requirejs).

If you want this result, CommonsChunkPlugin isn't what you are looking for. That plugin is to aggregate files that are used by different entries or other CommonChunkPlugin into one file.

I think what you are looking for `import()` or `require.ensure` to load "vendor" files on demand

otherwise [How to bundle vendor scripts separately and require them as needed with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329337/how-to-bundle-vendor-scripts-separately-and-require-them-as-needed-with-webpack/38733864#38733864) will work

Comment: I already took a look at `import()` and `require.ensure` and couldn't get it work properly. I will try the suggested question however and come back to you asap!

Comment: I updated my answer based on your proposal, but ran into another problem. Any ideas?