# Laravel, Datatable, Composer and Webpack : Good practices to allow developpers to customize my library in their projects

Tags: laravel, webpack, datatable, composer-php, laravel-mix

To set the context I am creating a CRUD application for Laravel. It is installed via composer and the sources are therefore in the **vendor/organization/package** directory.

In my project, I use [Datatable](https://datatables.net/). So I use Laravel Mix to compile my sources and a command line allows to copy JS and CSS compiled files into the **public** directory of the Laravel Host application.

I would like however that the developers who will use my library can customize the display of some Datatable cells. To do this you must use Datatable's **createdCell** configuration.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 3,
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      if ( cellData < 1 ) {
        $(td).css('color', 'red')
      }
    }
  } ]
});
```

The problem is that the JS sources of my project are already compiled...

For the moment I found a temporary solution that consists in leaving the JS sources in **vendor/organization/package** but copying the **webpack.mix.js** configuration into the Host application and asking the developers to compile themselves. The problem is that all JS dependencies must also be installed and it doesn't take very seriously to force the developers to compile sources before being able to use my library.

What are good practices to achieve this objective?

The following source may help, but I confess I don't know how to apply it to Laravel:
[How to bundle vendor scripts separately and require them as needed with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329337/how-to-bundle-vendor-scripts-separately-and-require-them-as-needed-with-webpack/38733864#38733864)

Thank you for your help.