# Can we use webpack to bundle application and libraries used by application seperately?

Tags: webpack

I have an application and I want to perform bundling for same. However unlike single bundle for everything , I want to create seperate bundle for application logic and third party libs , is that possible in webpack?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bundle vendor scripts separately and require them as needed with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329337/how-to-bundle-vendor-scripts-separately-and-require-them-as-needed-with-webpack)